Given that $\sin x+\sin3x +\sin5x = 1$, $\cos x +\cos3x +\cos5x = \sqrt{2} + 1$, find the value of $\tan3x$. Are there any mistakes in this topic?
Given the equations:
$$\sin x + \sin 3x + \sin 5x = 1,$$
$$\cos x + \cos 3x + \cos 5x = \sqrt{2} + 1,$$
we are asked to find the value of $\tan 3x$.
Firstly, let's use the sum-to-product formulas for sine and cosine:
For sine:
$$\sin A + \sin B = 2\sin\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right),$$
For cosine:
$$\cos A + \cos B = 2\cos\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right).$$
Applying these to our equations, we get:
For the first equation:
$$\sin x + \sin 5x = 2\sin\left(\frac{x+5x}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x-5x}{2}\right) = 2\sin(3x)\cos(-2x) = 2\sin(3x)\cos(2x),$$
and thus:
$$2\sin(3x)\cos(2x) + \sin 3x = 1.$$
For the second equation:
$$\cos x + \cos 5x = 2\cos\left(\frac{x+5x}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x-5x}{2}\right) = 2\cos(3x)\cos(-2x) = 2\cos(3x)\cos(2x),$$
and thus:
$$2\cos(3x)\cos(2x) + \cos 3x = \sqrt{2} + 1.$$
Now we solve for $\sin(3x)$ and $\cos(3x)$:
From the first equation:
$$2\sin(3x)\cos(2x) + \sin 3x = 1,$$
$$\Rightarrow \sin 3x (2\cos(2x) + 1) = 1.$$
From the second equation:
$$2\cos(3x)\cos(2x) + \cos 3x = \sqrt{2} + 1,$$
$$\Rightarrow \cos 3x (2\cos(2x) + 1) = \sqrt{2} + 1.$$
Dividing the two equations to eliminate $\cos(2x)$, we get:
$$\frac{\sin 3x (2\cos(2x) + 1)}{\cos 3x (2\cos(2x) + 1)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} + 1},$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{\sin 3x}{\cos 3x} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} + 1},$$
$$\Rightarrow \tan 3x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} + 1}.$$
To rationalize the denominator, we multiply the numerator and denominator by the conjugate $(\sqrt{2} - 1)$:
$$\tan 3x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} + 1} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{2} - 1}{\sqrt{2} - 1},$$
$$\Rightarrow \tan 3x = \sqrt{2} - 1.$$
That's the process of doing it by hand. However, using mathematica software to calculate the value of tan3x, the result is no solution. Is there a mistake in the question?


If $x = \frac {\pi}{24}$ is a solution to $\tan 3x = \sqrt 2 - 1.$ So,  $\frac {\sin \frac {\pi}{24} + \sin 3\frac {\pi}{24} + \sin 5\frac {\pi}{24}}{\cos \frac {\pi}{24} + \cos 3\frac {\pi}{24} + \cos 5\frac {\pi}{24}} = \frac {1}{1+\sqrt 2}$  However, that does not mean that $\sin \frac {\pi}{24} + \sin 3\frac {\pi}{24} + \sin 5\frac {\pi}{24} = 1$

I don't think there is a solution for $x$ that solves both the sin and cos equations...

@cambridgecircus What method did you use to get it without a solution?

Technically your answer is mathematically correct and vacuous, and practically you will also get full credit since the solution probably didn't account for the nonexistence of solutions.

@Trebor The actual situation should be that the questioner does not know that the premise of the question is not valid, but just changes a few numbers randomly through the method of solving this kind of problem

Potentially there exists a complex solution, where the complex tangent does indeed yield your $\sqrt{2}-1$. Oh and my method? A graphing calculator :)

@cambridgecircus A numerical root calculated by a computer?

Probably one more typo in a text book

@cambridgecircus You are, of course, right in that there aren't any values of $x$ that work. I want to add that the method in my answer shows that there aren't any complex answers either!

We know that
$$
\exp(ix) + \exp(3ix) + \exp(5ix) = \sqrt{2} + 1 + i
$$
and therefore $\exp(ix)$ belongs to the biquadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, i)$ and not to any of its proper subfields. The only algebraic integers of the form $\exp(ix)$ ($x$ real) in this field are the roots of unity, and the only roots of unity in this field are the $8$th roots of unity. So $\exp(ix)$ would have to be some primitive eighth root of unity, i.e. of the form $\frac{\pm\sqrt{2} \pm i\sqrt{2}}{2}$. But this gives $x$ an odd multiple of $\pi/4$, and this doesn't satisfy the given equation for the sine function. We conclude that the setup is impossible.

A previous version of this said  "the only algebraic numbers of the form $\exp(ix)$ are roots of unity" which is certainly false.

Another point of view comes from elimination theory. Below I will derive an equation that the values of the sums of sines and cosines, call them $u$ and $v$ respectively, must satisfy for a solution to exist.

Write $t=e^{ix}$. The problem is about the relation of the possible values of the pair of functions
$$
u=\sin5x+\sin3x+\sin x=-\frac{1}{2} i \left(t^5-\frac{1}{t^5}\right)-\frac{1}{2} i
   \left(t^3-\frac{1}{t^3}\right)-\frac{1}{2} i
   \left(t-\frac{1}{t}\right)
$$
and
$$
v=\cos5x+\cos3x+\cos x=\frac{1}{2} \left(t^5+\frac{1}{t^5}\right)+\frac{1}{2}
   \left(t^3+\frac{1}{t^3}\right)+\frac{1}{2}
   \left(t+\frac{1}{t}\right).
$$
Using the language of function fields we see that $u,v\in\Bbb{C}(t)$, in other words they are both rational functions of the unknown $t$. The field $F=\Bbb{C}(t)$ has transcendence degree one over $\Bbb{C}$. Therefore any two elements of $F$ are algebraically dependent, and must satisfy a polynomial equation with complex constant coefficients.
Finding that equation is a bit taxing by paper and pencil alone, but the algorithms from elimination theory (look up Gröbner bases) come to the rescue. I fired up Mathematica, and gave it the inputs:
s = (t - 1/t)/(2 I) + (t^3 - 1/t^3)/(2 I) + (t^5 - 1/t^5)/(2 I)
c = (t + 1/t)/(2) + (t^3 + 1/t^3)/(2) + (t^5 + 1/t^5)/(2)
GroebnerBasis[{Expand[s t^5] - u t^5, Expand[c t^5] - v t^5}, {u, v}, {t}]

where the last command first clears the denominators (Gröbner basis -algorithms want polynomials), introduces the variables $u$ and $v$, and then tells it to eliminate $t$ from the system of two equations in the three unknowns ($u,v,t$) if/when possible. It gave me
$$R:=u^{10}+5 u^8 v^2-9 u^8+10 u^6 v^4-36 u^6 v^2+24 u^6+10 u^4 v^6-54
   u^4 v^4+48 u^4 v^2-16 u^4+5 u^2 v^8-36 u^2 v^6+24 u^2
   v^4+v^{10}-9 v^8$$
meaning that irrespective of the value of $t$, the quantities $u,v$ satisfy the equation $R=0$. By way of confirmation I checked that if we substitute the earlier formulas for $u$ and $v$ respectively, the quantity $R$ simplifies to zero.
The conclusion:

For the system of equations $\sin x+\sin 3x+ \sin 5x =u$, $\cos x+\cos
3x+\cos 5x=v$ to have a solution, it is necessary that $$R(u,v)=0,$$
where $R$ is the above bivariate polynomial.

We see that
$$
R(1,1+\sqrt2)=-1808-1280\sqrt2
$$
giving an overkill confirmation to the conclusion of the other answerers: the system has no solutions. We also see that $R(1,0)=0=R(0,3)$ as expected given that $x=\pi/2$ corresponds to $u=1,v=0$, and $x=0$ corresponds to $u=0,v=3$. Similarly $x=\pi/4$ yields $u=\sqrt2/2$, $v=-\sqrt2/2$ and $R=0$.

Observe that all of the above applies to complex values of $u$ and $v$ as well. So the values of the sines or cosines may also be complex, or real numbers outside the usual range $[-1,1]$.

Great!  btw, it seems GroebnerBasis is OK with some fractions, like here

The function $\sin x + \sin 3x + \sin 5x - 1$ is periodic with period $2\pi$. In every period, there are five roots. In the range $[0, 2\pi)$, the roots are: $x \approx 0.115, 0.729, 1.571, 2.413, 3.026$. Likewise, the function $\cos x + \cos 3x + \cos 5x - \sqrt{2} - 1$ is periodic with period $2 \pi$. In every period, there are two roots. In the range $[0, 2\pi)$, the roots are: $x \approx 0.189, 6.095$.
Thus, there are no solutions to the pair of equations, matching what Mathematica says.
Yes, there's a mistake in the question: No such $x$ exists. Asking the value of $\tan 3x$ is meaningless.

How are these numerical solutions solved?

@csn899 I used Desmos

Let us prove that the system has no real solution.
Clearly, $\cos 3x > 0$.
From the system, we have
\begin{align*}
 \sin 3x \, (2\cos 2x + 1) &= 1, \tag{1}\\
 \cos 3x\, (2\cos 2x + 1) &= \sqrt{2} + 1.\tag{2}
\end{align*}
Using $\cos 3x > 0$ and (2), we have $2\cos 2x + 1 > 0$.
$(1)^2 + (2)^2$ gives
$$(2\cos 2x + 1)^2 = 1 + (\sqrt{2} + 1)^2.$$
Thus, we have
$$2\cos 2x + 1 = \sqrt{1 + (\sqrt{2} + 1)^2}, \tag{3}$$
and
$$\cos 3x = \frac{\sqrt{2} + 1}{\sqrt{1 + (\sqrt{2} + 1)^2}}. \tag{4}$$
Using $\cos 2x = 2\cos^2 x - 1$ and (3), we have
$$\cos^2 x = \frac{\sqrt{1 + (\sqrt{2} + 1)^2} + 1}{4}. \tag{5}$$
Using $\cos 3x = 4\cos^3 x - 3\cos x$ and (5), we have
\begin{align*}
 4\cos^2 3x &= 4(4\cos^3 x - 3\cos x)^2\\
 &= 4\cos^2 x \, (4\cos^2 x - 3)^2\\
 &= \left(\sqrt{1 + (\sqrt{2} + 1)^2} + 1\right) \, \left(\sqrt{1 + (\sqrt{2} + 1)^2} + 1 - 3\right)^2
\end{align*}
which results in (using (4))
$$4\Big(\frac{\sqrt{2} + 1}{\sqrt{1 + (\sqrt{2} + 1)^2}}\Big)^2
= \left(\sqrt{1 + (\sqrt{2} + 1)^2} + 1\right) \, \left(\sqrt{1 + (\sqrt{2} + 1)^2} + 1 - 3\right)^2. \tag{6}$$
However, (6) is not true. Indeed, we have
$$\mathrm{LHS}_{(6)} = 2 + \sqrt{2}, $$
and (using $\sqrt{1 + (\sqrt{2} + 1)^2}
= \sqrt{4 + 2\sqrt{2}} < \sqrt{4 + 4} = 2\sqrt{2}$)
$$\mathrm{RHS}_{(6)}
< (2\sqrt{2} + 1)(2\sqrt{2} + 1 - 3)^2
= 16\sqrt{2} - 20 < 2 + \sqrt{2}.$$
Thus, the system has no real solution.
